# Is it possible to share the same jvm process when opening a project in sbt, vscode and using metals/bloop?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm not sure what is going on under the covers, but when I open VS code with the metals plugin, I understand bloop is running behind the scenes.

If I then open a terminal and run sbt on the same project, is it sharing the same jvm process to run the application etc. or is it running multiple jvm processes?

When I open the project in VS Code, a terminal is opened automatically and it seems to be running a ~compile on the project from the inital opening of the project.

The goal is to understand how much memory this will use on my laptop and to share bloop if possible.

Comment: You can use `jps` to check how many processes they are. In my case, since I installed bloop manually I have 3 processes. one for bloop, a second for metals and the third one for sbt.

Comment: Bloop attempts to have one global process. sbt runs several clients but they might be aware of each other in a way (they will wait for other process blocking operation if they depend on it at well). Metals might also have several servers as you can install one instance globally and VSCode could install its own version to avoid depending on external programs.